# getPaginationCount() function not working in Laravel's Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm pulling out the Eloquent module to use it separately, but I have access to the QueryBuilder functions. They're all working except for that one.

When I run a count() and a getPaginationCount(), the count() returns the correct value, but getPaginationCount() just returns the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder object, as if I didn't command a query to run. However, I can see 2 queries in the query log, and oddly, they both run the same query.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';  

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;  

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection(array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => TECHDB_HOST,
    'database'  => TECHDB_DBNAME,
    'username'  => TECHDB_USER,
    'password'  => TECHDB_PASS,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => ''
));

$capsule->bootEloquent();


class Indicator extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $table = "indicator_performance";
}

$query = Indicator::where('symbol', '=', 'IBM')->forPage(1,2);

var_dump($query->count()); //Correctly prints '13'

var_dump($query->getPaginationCount()); //dumps the 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder' object
```

Here is the query log:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select count(*) as aggregate from `indicator_performance` where `symbol` = ? limit 2 offset 0' (length=93)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'IBM' (length=3)
      'time' => float 4.85
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select count(*) as aggregate from `indicator_performance` where `symbol` = ? limit 2 offset 0' (length=93)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'IBM' (length=3)
      'time' => float 4.24
```

**EDIT:**

It seems I've exposed a more general bug with the `count()` function when used after a `forPage()` call. Have a look at these results:

```
$query = Indicator::where('symbol', '=', 'IBM');

var_dump($query->count()); //Correctly returns '13'
var_dump($query->forPage(0, 5)->count()); //Correctly returns '13'
var_dump($query->forPage(1, 5)->count()); //Correctly returns '13'
var_dump($query->forPage(2, 5)->count()); //Returns null. Should return '13' or '3', depending on implementation.
```

Comment: What happens if you don't run `count()`, and just run `getPaginationCount()`? I don't know for sure, but maybe `count()` is changing the current query state somehow that's confusing the pagination count.

Comment: Removing count() doesn't change the results unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code (and the Laravel):

1. `getPaginationCount()` called on the Eloquent Builder runs the method (on the Query Builder class) but doesn't return its result. Instead it returns itself as `$this`.
2. `getPaginationCount()` doesn't reset `limit` and `offset` on the query to get the count, which I suppose is a bug. This results in returning `null` whenever offset is set to anything higher than 1. `forPage($page)` will do that for `$page > 1`.

That being said, I suggest you either use `count()` instead of `getPaginationCount()` or:

```
// first get the count
$count = $query->getQuery()  // get the base Query Builder directly
    ->getPaginationCount();  // in order to return the count

// then use forPage
$query->forPage(1,5);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting the purpose of the `getPaginationCount()` function, but I thought it was supposed to return the number of records returned on the page. If you make your `forPage()` call after `getPaginationCount()`, it would not return the count for the correct page. E.g. if you have 13 records and a page size of 5, the count for the 3rd page should be 3.

Comment: I seem to have exposed a more general bug with the `count()` function when used after a `forPage()`. Have a look at my edit in the OP.

Comment: Yes, but it's more general, not just after `forPage`. It concerns any situation when offset is set on the query.